# How to detect closing of a browser in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, browser

I want to know how to detect the closing of browser and also to trigger a function based on the detection in Django web framework. Someone please guide me if possible with code snippet.

I tried using JavaScript. It worked in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers
MAYO.

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote that worked in Firefox but not Chrome?

Comment: have you tried the `unload` event

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use JS and bind a synchronous XMLHttpRequest call to the unload DOM event.

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  $.ajax({url:"pageExit", async:false});
});
```

Comment: What if the user wants to refresh the page??

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {

  var e = e || window.event;

  if (e) {
    // do something here
  }

};
```